# Infinite magnetic fields requires infinite photons?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-electrodynamics

Recently I read that magnetic fields might be infinite. But that would require infinite photons, right? And is there any information about the amount of photons in the universe? Anyways if the universe had an infinite amount of photons wouldn't that lead to constant particle-antiparticle creation and annihilation?

Comment: Where did you read that magnetic fields are infinite, and what does that even mean?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform textbooks often say things like, "and the magnetic field extends in a dipole shape *out to infinity*".  Similarly with gravitational fields, etc.  I think this is a common, and understandable, point of confusion.

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix oh, so its about its *range*, not its *intensity*! That makes much more sense.

Comment: Hi Chess_Player To be sceptical about the infinite range is OK. Some say that this fields are excitements of overall an existing EM field. By this they avoid the difficulties associated with your question. I don't know your level of education, may be you could read about [How does the law of charge work at a fundamental level](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/321123/why-does-the-law-of-charge-work-at-a-fundamental-level/321394#321394).